# Compose event streams with a resettable delay on one of them

Tags: rxjs

I want to change the size of an element while it is being scrolled (touch pan, etc). In order to do that I intend to use touch events as observable sources. The size should grow when user starts to pan the element and should shrink 5s after user stopped.

In other words:
Given the streams of 'start' and 'end' events, immediately do the action on 'start' and delay the action on 'end'. But if during that delay new event 'start' come, the delay should be cancelled.

[Here](https://rx-marbles-online.herokuapp.com/?marblescode=//%20This%20is%20an%20example%20marble%20diagram%0D%0A//%20with%20one%20source%20%27a%27%20and%20%27foo%27%20operator%20acting%20on%20it.%0D%0A%0D%0Amarble%20foo_example%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20source%20start:%20%20%20%2B--S--S--S-------%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20source%20end:%20%20%20%20%20%2B---E---E------E-%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20operator%20foo:%20%20%20%2B--L-----------S-%7C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&scale=75&theme=default) is marble, the best I could do.

PS
Feel free to suggest a better title. I struggle to come up with something descriptive enough.

Comment: Sounds like `switchMap`. I might not understand very well what you want to do with 'end' events...

Comment: When 'end' event comes, wait `n` seconds and if no other 'start' comes then do action; else stop delay and wait for next 'end'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `start$` and `end$` are the Observable streams representing the **start** and **end** events, than I would probably proceed like this

```
start$.pipe(
   // use tap to implement the side effect of growing the size of an element
   // the event is passed assuming that it contains somehow the reference to the element
   // whose size has to grow
   tap(event => growSize(event)),
   // any time a start event is notified, we pass the control to the end$ stream
   // if a new start event is notified, the subscription to end$ will be unsubscribed
   // a new subscription will be establishes, which means that a new delay will start
   switchMap(() => 
       end$.pipe(
           // delay 5 seconds
           delay(5000),
           // decrease the size of the element as a side effect
           tap(event => decreaseSize(event)),
       )
   )
)
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `merge` your start and end triggers and use `debounceTime` with `filter`:

```js
merge(start$, end$).pipe(
  debounceTime(5000),
  filter(event => event === 'end')
);
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67917539?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=65) to play with.